# Is there an "Enter" or "Tab" excel VBA to perform on a webpage?

Tags: html, excel, vba, forms

I am trying to fill out a web form from excel VBA using `IE.getElementsByName("recipientName")(0).Value = "Sal"` it correctly types "Sal" but when I run `IE.getElementsByClassName("btn")(0).Click` it says the field is empty.

I need to know what is the VBA code to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> as I used `IE.getElementsByName("recipientName")(0).Select` to select all text and if I can get <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> VBA code it might work.

Other solutions are welcome.

Please help me and thank you so much for reading my question.

Comment: Would `Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"` help?

Comment: You may need to .Focus before entering text or fire an html event(s) - usually indicated by event listeners. Additionally, verifying entering value in correct place. If you can share an url that would help. It is better to find a way that avoids sendkeys with ie automation if possible.

Comment: Can you post the html or link for the site, it’s better to work with elements then send keys

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid-namesplit ng-invalid ng-invalid-blank ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" id="recipientName" name="recipientName" placeholder="e.g. Mr John Smith" tabindex="13" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" ng-model="parcel.recipientName" ng-focus="latestOrderItem.orderItem.recipientNameFocused = true" ng-blur="latestOrderItem.orderItem.recipientNameFocused = false" maxlength="64" value="" mh-not-blank="" mh-trim-on-blur="" mh-monitor-focus="" mh-split-name="" aria-invalid="true">

Comment: QHarr Thank you for your suggestion but it did not work. i have just noted in the HTML autocomplete is Off.

Answer (score 0):

You can trying using send keys which sends keystrokes

```
With Application
    .SendKeys "{TAB}"
    .SendKeys "~" 'this sends the enter key 
End With
```

Comment: you may want to replace the curly quotes with straight quotes.

Comment: Hi,  Scott this did not work, when i run code it press tab/enter inside macro window not in internet explorer.

Comment: My apologies. You need to make sure that IE is activated. This will send keys to the active application. Are you switching between IE and excel? How are you opening IE?

Comment: Hi, Internet explorer is already opened. Inside the vba code it searches for the tab name and than it fills the form. i am new to VBA codes. if you could write a "enter" code for me please in full. where do i need to place I.E? Thank you so much Scott for replying.

Comment: Hi, it still entering tab/enter into VBA and not in IE. screenshot of VB and webpage https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrL7o.png